# Unable to import Android Web Driver library using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to use the android web driver but the eclipse IDE can't find the class definitions for the following set of imports

import org.openqa.selenium.android;
import org.openqa.selenium.android;

i have already followed the procedure as specified in the following link

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

but still i cant import these two classes

so anyone with some suggestions please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: Please check if you added the required jars in your project.

Comment: yeah already did, i included all of them, Some of them are :  android_webdriver_library.jar
android_webdriver_library-srcs.jar
guava-12.0.jar
selenium-java-2.21.0.jar
selenium-server-2.21.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar

Comment: Have you followed all the steps? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Using_the_Remote_Server

Comment: yeah i did, i set up the server, installed android server as told in this tutorial,, imported all the jars, but still i cant figure out what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
 import org.openqa.selenium.android.*;

The classes are within package org.openqa.selenium.android

Comment: i solved the problem but what happens now is that app crashes when being opened in the android emulator, i have already exported the jar files that the app may require, so any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you check LOGCAT logs. That will tell what is exception. To go in detail you may try to run the code in debug mode. That will help you find where and why code is giving crash. It may happen the element is not available or wrong action you are doing.